# How to insert data in table y that related with table x 0 - 0/1 (x,y)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I am working on an EF Using Model First.

I want to add more details in table that specify for special categorys 
but when I add these details that depend on adding data in a product table I get an exception.

[image]

```
public static void addproduct(ProductViewModel vm ,string userid)
        {
            var model = Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, Product>(vm);
            model.CountSell = 0;

            byte[] binaries = new byte[vm.postprofilimgae.ContentLength];
            vm.postprofilimgae.InputStream.Read(binaries, 0, vm.postprofilimgae.ContentLength);
            model.ProfileImage = binaries;
            foreach (var file in vm.postProductimages)
            {
                var filedetails = new ProductImage();
                var data = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                filedetails.ContentLength = file.ContentLength;
                filedetails.FileName = file.FileName;
                file.InputStream.Read(data, 0, file.ContentLength);
                filedetails.ProductImage1 = data;
                filedetails.ProductID= model.ProductID;
                model.ProductImages.Add(filedetails);
            }
            using (var db = new Entities())
            {
                model.ActivationID = db.ActivationStatus.Single(x => x.Name == "Active").ActivationID;
                model.SubCategoryID = vm.SubCategoryID;
                model.EmployeeID= db.Employees.Single(x => x.UserID == userid).EmployeeID;
                model.CountSell = 0;

                VichDetails detailsmodel = new VichDetails();
                if (db.SubCategories.Single(x=>x.SubCategoryID == vm.SubCategoryID).MainCategoryID == db.MainCategories.Single(x=> x.Name == Categories.vehicles).MainCategoryID)
                {
                    VichDetails moredetails = new VichDetails();
                    detailsmodel = Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, VichDetails>(vm);
                    //detailsmodel.ProductID = model.ProductID;
                    db.VichDetails.Add(detailsmodel);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                model.VichDetailsID = detailsmodel.Id;
                db.Products.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

I get this exception:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Product you will want to consider adding:

```
public virtual VichDetail VichDetail { get; set; }
```

and then instead of:

```
if (db.SubCategories.Single(x=>x.SubCategoryID == vm.SubCategoryID).MainCategoryID == db.MainCategories.Single(x=> x.Name == Categories.vehicles).MainCategoryID)
{
    VichDetails moredetails = new VichDetails();
    detailsmodel = Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, VichDetails>(vm);
    db.VichDetails.Add(detailsmodel);
}
db.SaveChanges();
model.VichDetailsID = detailsmodel.Id;
db.Products.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();
```

it would look like:

```
if (db.SubCategories.Single(x=>x.SubCategoryID == vm.SubCategoryID).MainCategoryID == db.MainCategories.Single(x=> x.Name == Categories.vehicles).MainCategoryID)
{
    VichDetails detailsmodel = Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, VichDetails>(vm);
    model.VichDetails = detailsModel;
}
db.Products.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The issue you are encountering is that while you are setting the new VichDetail ID on your Product before saving the product, you have only associated the Product, not necessarily the VichDetail. I.e.
`if (db.SubCategories.Single(x=>x.SubCategoryID == vm.SubCategoryID).MainCategoryID == db.MainCategories.Single(x=> x.Name == Categories.vehicles).MainCategoryID)`

If this condition is false, the VichDetail is not added to the DbContext.

The code is rather confusing to look at as you are creating a VichDetail, but then checking that condition before creating another VichDetail "moredetails" which doesn't look to be used, before mapping the original details from the view model. If that condition doesn't pass you will have an empty VichDetails (detailsmodel) with likely a default ID (0?) which would be set on your Product. (model)

You cannot simply move the `model.VichDetailsID = detailsmodel.id` inside your conditions, since you're relying on setting FK IDs which won't be available until the related entity is saved to the DbContext. Navigation properties are generally a lot easier to interact with than messing around with PKs and FKs in your entities. Let EF do the lifting for associating the relationships.

If your entities already have these navigation properties, then you'll want to use those and avoid setting FKs directly.